# Does $f$ not differentiable on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ imply $f$ not analytic at $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In an exercise of type:

> Let $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C $ be defined so and so. Show that $f$ is not analytic anywhere.

I saw the following approach: First show that $f$ is not differentiable on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ and then say:

> Thus, $f$ is not analytic at any $z \ne 0$. It is not analytic at $z = 0$ either since every neighborhood of $0$ contains a nonzero point, at which $f$ cannot be differentiable.

Source: Problem 4b [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~nikhil/courses/185.f15/midterm1.pdf) and its solution [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~nikhil/courses/185.f15/mt1sol.pdf).

It looks like the the following statement had been used:

> If $f$ is not differentiable on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ then $f$ not analytic at $0$.

I must have misunderstood something but why would it make sense if there are functions $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C $ that are differentiable only at one point? E.g. $f(z)=|z|^2$.

**EDIT:**

It all makes more sense now. I thought that $$\text{holomorphic} \iff \text{complex differentiable} \iff \text{complex analytic}$$ (depending in which order one introduces the definitions).

Comment: what definition of holomorphic are you using?

Comment: @MarkJoshi: I had no idea there are non-equivalent definitions of complex differentiability. I am using this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function#Definition

Comment: "Differentiable" and "holomorphic" are not the same thing.  A function can indeed be differentiable only at a single point, but it is holomorphic at a point (in the usual definition) if it is differentiable not just at the point but in a neighbourhood of the point.

Comment: It does not make sense to speak about holomorphicity at a point. Holomorphicity is a property about functions on *open* sets. A singleton is not open in any meaningful topology for the purposes of calculus.

Comment: Okay with that correction: it is not true that non-differentiability on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ implies non-differentiability at $0$ and your example of $f(z) = |z|^2$ is often the prototypical example of this.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: so the linked solution is false?

Comment: Well complex-analytic is the same as holomorphic, so if you show that the function is not holomorphic on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ (by showing it is not differentiable on that set), you know that it cannot be holomorphic on $\Bbb C$ or on any of its open subsets. So the linked solution is not false, it is just using the two different terms which can be confusing if you're not thinking about it carefully.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: oh, it all makes sense now. I thought that holomorphic $\iff$ complex differentiable $\iff$ complex analytic (depending in which order one introduces the definitions).

Comment: Glad you understand :)